# Access Time Capsule from Android phone

Tags: time-capsule, file-sharing, android

Can I access the contents of the "Data" folder on computers other than Macs? For instance, can I access the Time Capsule from my Android phone?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "access"? If you mean editing files and/or copying files to and from Time Capsule, you might not be able to do that since the hard drive in Time Capsule is formatted using Mac Journaled file system. If all you want is to view files, some Android apps might be able to access the device over network.

Comment: Access as in be able to copy stuff from the time capsule to the phone. Basically use it as any other NAS

Answer (score 1):

The Time Capsule (and external disks connected to an Airport) supports AFP and SMB protocols. If your device supports either of these you can access the HD.

Answer (score 0):

access the time capsule - easy. load file manager hd ( play stor - free) and use the menu to create a new lan  connection. top menu in upper left / network / create. input details and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

use x-plore app to acces files on time capsule hdd